# Rails Search Returning Blank Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I am trying to implement a simple search feature on my site. Currently, when I use my search bar it will work, but if the result is not found then it will pull up a blank page. I am using PostgreSQL

this is my form in recipes/index.html.erb

```
    <%= form_with(url: recipes_path, method: :get, local: true) do |form| %>
      <%= form.text_field(:term, {class: 'form-control', type:'search', 
          arialabel:'search', placeholder: 'search by recipe name'})%>
      <%= form.submit 'Search', class: 'btn btn-dark bg-dark' %>
    <% end %>
```

this is my controller index action in the recipes_controller.rb

```
    def index
      @recipes = if params[:term]
                   Recipe.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:term]}")
                 else
                   Recipe.all
      end
@categories = Category.all
end
```

I would like to redirect the user back to to the index view and display a message that says something like "the recipe was not found, please search for a different recipe."

Comment: Hi, can you share your view file too? where is the form located is it in the view under the same controller?

Comment: the form is in the index view, and the Recipe controller contains the corresponding index action

Comment: I don't think the index.html.erb has code to show the result of `@recipes`. You need to put `@recipes` in a table or any other format to show the result in index.html.erb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Index file,

```
<%= form_tag('/recepies/', :method => :get, :role => 'form') do %>                   
  <%= text_field_tag :term, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Search"%>                                    
  <button class='glyphicon glyphicon-search' type="search">
  </button>
<% end %>
```

In your controller,

```
def index
  if params[:term].present?
    @recipes = Recepie.all
    @recipes = @recipes.find_term(params[:term].strip) if params[:term].present?

    if  @recipes.blank?  {
          flash[:notice] = 'the recipe was not found, please search for a different recipe.' 
     }
    end

  else
    @recipes = Recepie.all
  end
end
```

In your Model,

```
def self.find_term(term)
    recipes = all
    recipes = posts.where("recipes.term= ?", term)      
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> when I use my search bar it will work, but if the result is not found
>   then it will pull up a blank page.

So your search works but it has no results.

> I would like to redirect the user back to to the index view and
>   display a message that says something like "the recipe was not found,
>   please search for a different recipe."

You could do something like `@recipes.any?` to check if you got some results. If you check in the controller you can redirect and use the `flash` for messages, or you can simply do it in the view and render the message.

PS: Not that you ask, but I really like to use [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) for complex search functionality.